# C# Moving XmlNode from Parent

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

XML is:

```
<RNC id="00">
    <abc1>
    </abc1>
    <abc2>
    </abc2>
</RNC>
<RNC id="01" >
    <abc3>
    </abc3>
    <abc4>
    </abc4>
</RNC>
<RNC id="01">
    <abc5>
    </abc5>
    <abc6>
    </abc6>
</RNC>
```

My code validates if the XmlNode with id=1 is duplicated, but if it exists I would like to move abc5 and abc6 to the first occurence of RNC id=01 and have the following:

```
<RNC id="00">
    <abc1>
    </abc1>
    <abc2>
    </abc2>
</RNC>
<RNC id="01" >
    <abc3>
    </abc3>
    <abc4>
    </abc4>
    <abc5>
    </abc5>
    <abc6>
    </abc6>
</RNC>
```

How can this be achieved with C#? I am not using LINQ, I am using XmlDocument, XmlNodeList and XmlNode.

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to say that, when I read the source XML, there are no duplicated RNC Nodes, this is a pre check as the point here is when having RNC ID0, ID1 and ID2, change ID2 to ID1 and then join all XML nodes.

Comment: Any reason why you're *not* using LINQ to XML?

Comment: Yes, I found that findind a specific XmlNode and change it's inner text easier to code, for me at least, and in what I am developing I think it makes more sense.

Comment: what have you tried so far? any attempts to iterate nodes and check ID's or write xpath query to return all nodes with `id=0` and then move child nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One feature of navigating through a document is `XPath`, a kind of query language for XML documents. XPath stands for XML Path Language. It’s a language that is specifically designed for addressing parts of an XML document.

1)Select all duplicates ids

You can use following xpath:

`//RNC[@id= following::RNC/@id and not(@id = preceding::RNC/@id)]`

`find next node with the same id, work in one direction`

2)Iterates thru them with `SelectNodes("//RNC[@id='id']")`

3)Add child nodes from second RNC to first, then remove first from xmlDoc

```
foreach(var chNode in secondNode.ChildNodes)
{
    firstNode.AppendChild(chNode );
}   
Doc.RemoveChild(secondNode);
```

Comment: That is my issue exactly, how can I add childs from 2nd to 1st and then delete them?

Comment: Update my answer with code sample

Comment: Another update with duplicates finding xpath

Answer (score 0):

I have a string with the new RNC ID, lets say ID1, so the ID2 will be modified to ID1, then I check if that ID1 is duplicated as per low

```
using(XmlNodeList RNC_LIST = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("RNC"))
{
    foreach(XmlNode RNC in RNC_LIST)
    {
        if (RNC.Attributes["id"].Value == target_rnc)
        {
            /// Move the XmlNodes Here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<Root>" +
                "<RNC id=\"00\">" +
                    "<abc1>" +
                    "</abc1>" +
                    "<abc2>" +
                    "</abc2>" +
                "</RNC>" +
                "<RNC id=\"01\">" +
                    "<abc3>" +
                    "</abc3>" +
                    "<abc4>" +
                    "</abc4>" +
                "</RNC>" +
                "<RNC id=\"01\">" +
                    "<abc5>" +
                    "</abc5>" +
                    "<abc6>" +
                    "</abc6>" +
                "</RNC>" +
                "</Root>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var groups = root.Elements("RNC").GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("id").Value).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                if (group.Count() > 1)
                {
                    var all = group.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                    for (int index = all.Count() - 2; index >= 0; index--)
                    {
                        all[index].Add(all[index + 1].Elements());
                        all[index + 1].RemoveAll();
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```